# Get smaller size of image, get_the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

My theme is using this code in a shortcode to get the image of the post. However, this is the full size image and i am looking to get the small thumbnail instead. How could I do this?

```
   $image_output       = '<div class="x-recent-posts-img">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'entry', NULL ) . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code to:

```
$image_output = '<div class="x-recent-posts-img">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail', NULL ) . '</div>';
```

See in the Codex:

[Thumbnail Sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes)

[get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

Comment: yes I have tried that, but still i am getting the full size image..

Comment: Sure you editing the right code? @joanna-mikalai